# Some mouse clicks not detected

Tags: mouse, mouse-click

My mouse is now five years old and starting to give up. When I click, the click is not allways recognized by the OS. Sometimes I have to click again for an action to happen. If I click very hard it always responds. Tested mouse on other PC, and it behaved the same (which means it's something with the mouse.)

Can I fix this somehow? It's a Razer Diamondback.

Comment: Did you Google "cleaning Razer Diamondback"? Gives plenty of hits

Comment: I feel your pain. I loved my Diamondback and had to switch to a cyborg RAT 7 because the side button I use for on the fly sensitivity gave up. Just out of interest, is it the first gen magma or limited edition plasma, or the 3g version? I don't know if 'pressing hard' would affect the response if it was just down to dirt. Wouldn't it be a worn component issue?

Comment: +1 for addressing potential high end mouse problems.  It's not every day I care spend a bunch of money on a mouse, but when I do, I get a Best Buy credit card and get my self in loads of debt :D

Comment: @JanDoggen I did not find anything good, would you mind helping me?